# aws cognito attribute 'address' doesn't follow its own documentation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

I was looking through aws docs at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html as I needed to update the address for a user. According to the docs it says it follows the openID spec which for an address is a json object.  However it errors on anything that is not a string.
I'm using the aws cli and calling it like so:

```
aws cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes --user-pool-id my_user_pool --username a@b.com --user-attributes Name=address,Value={"street_address": "123 Fake Street","locality": "Somewhere","postal_code":"AA1 1AA"}
```

the following also doesn't work:

```
aws cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes --user-pool-id my_user_pool --username a@b.com --user-attributes Name=address,Value="123 Fake Street, Somewhere"

Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter UserAttributes[0].Value, value: ['123 Fake 
Street', 'Somewhere'], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
```

Am I inputting something wrong or is aws docs incorrect and only allowing strings through

Comment: Encountering the same issue when trying to set an attribute to a string containing a comma...

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue as well, I couldn't find a solve in any of the AWS documentation but if you escape the comma it works.

`aws cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes --user-pool-id my_user_pool --username a@b.com --user-attributes Name=address,Value="123 Fake Street\, Somewhere"`

Comment: This still only allows the "formatted" property of the OIDC "address" claim to be presented in the ID Token. Personally I'm looking for the syntax that allows all (or a subset of) the standard "address" properties to be presented in the Cognito ID Token.